# Why is click event triggered on div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two jsfiddler setups with two divs:

[first setup](https://jsfiddle.net/3ugrLee9/)

```
<div class="d1" style="background-color: red; position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; right; 0; left: 0; right: 0;">
    <div class="d2" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: green; position: relative; top: 100px; left: 100px;"></div>
</div>

$(function() {
  $('.d1').on('click', function(event) {
    alert('clicked on red');
  });

  $('.d2').on('click', function(event) {
    alert('clicked on green');
  });
});
```

[second setup](https://jsfiddle.net/3ugrLee9/1/)

```
<div class="d1" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: red; position: relative; top: 100px; left: 100px;">
</div>
    <div class="d2" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: green; position: relative; top: 100px; left: 100px;"></div>

$(function() {
  $('.d1').on('click', function(event) {
    alert('clicked on red');
  });

  $('.d2').on('click', function(event) {
    alert('clicked on green');
  });
});
```

In both cases I click on the green div, and without releasing a mouse button I move the pointer to hover over red div and then release the button. In the first setup the `click` event is triggered for the red div, and in the second setup it's not triggered.

Why the difference?

Comment: @Paulie_D, Yes but if alert is being fired for the element where event is initiated, it should happen in the second case as well right ?

Comment: @Paulie_D, Yeah! Wasn't quiet obvious! Thanks mate :)

Comment: Please don't change the question once answers have been posted and accepted. ASK A NEW QUESTION.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a `click` is shorthand for a `mousedown` AND a `mouseup` set of events.

[**JQuery**](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

> The click event is only triggered after this exact series of events:
>
> - The mouse button is depressed while the pointer is inside the
>     element.
> - The mouse button is released while the pointer is inside the
>     element.

If both conditions aren't met the function doesn't fire.

So

> click on the green div, and without releasing a mouse button I move the pointer to hover over red div and then release the button.

Only the red function fires because the `mousedown` happens on the green div **which is inside the red div and so the red div is also clicked** and the `mouseup` happens on the red div.

So `mousedown` and `mouseup` happen only on the red div.

Comment: thanks, can you please take a look at my edit, especially this comment `this is how I can do to ensure that click is triggered `? I need to prevent hiding of modal dialog when the mouse down occurred on the dialog and mouse released outside of the dialog - here is the example of the [modal window](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Comment: You need to ask a second NEW question for that so as to not invalidate anything already posted. I've rolled back the edit so you can ask a new question.

Comment: Done, please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572530/correct-way-to-prevent-triggering-click-if-inner-element-is-not-hovered-when-m)

Answer (score 0):

In the above setup(1), you have the green one as your child of the red one. So, when you click on green, it automates the click over the parent, so even the red div gets clicked.

In general, you won't find this problems as you do not have any click event bound to the parent when a click event is already bound to a child element as  in case of setup(2).

The click on the parent would not trigger a click on child unless, the mouse is in the defined domain of the child or in other words, if someone is clicking on the child element itself.

Comment: OP does not click on the green!

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

In your first step why it works is as other answers mentioned, green div is inside the red div. So if you click green div click event for green div fired. Same time due to JS beautiful feature **Event Bubbling** same click event passed to it's parent which is red div.

So when you click on your green div mouse down event fires for the green div and red div same time. and when you mouse move to the red div and release it click event for the red div fires but not for the green div. Because to have a click event you need to have mouse down and mouse up. But in your case mouse up didn't fired for the green div.

In your second setup tow divs are next to each other not one inside another. so events attached to both divs are individual.

All other answers are correct I just explain the theory :D

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get pass this problem you could do something like

```
$(document).on("mousedown", function(e){
  var tar = $(e.target).attr('class');
  $(document).on("mouseup",function(){
    if (tar == "d1"){
      alert("clicked on red");
    }
    if(tar == "d2"){
      alert("clicked on green");
    }
  $(document).off("mouseup");
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/448ugz1v/3/)

Not sure if this is the case but just bringing this up.