# Correct way to prevent triggering `click` if inner element is not hovered when mouse is released

Tags: javascript

I need to prevent hiding of a modal dialog when user clicks on the dialog, then moves the mouse outside of the dialog, and releases it. The dialog is placed inside outer div on which the `click` event is registered. [Here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) is the example of the modal dialog and its setup.

So I've done the following:

```
var pointerDownElement = null;

$('.d1').on('mousedown', function(event) {
    // this is how I do it to prevent triggering of click event
    pointerDownElement = event.target;

    // this is how a browser does it
    pointerDownElement = event.currentTarget;
});

$('.d1').on('mouseup', function(event) {
    var element = event.target;
    if (element === pointerDownElement) {
        console.log('triggering click');
    }
});
```

Is this approach correct?

Comment: I would say so yes, with of course proper event handling but yes it is the way i'd go about it.

Comment: You will probably have to call event.preventDefault() from a click handler

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the right track.  Slightly modified code:

```
var pointerDownElement = null;

$('.d1').on('mousedown', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    pointerDownElement = event.currentTarget;
    return false;
});

$('.d1').on('mouseup', function(event) {
    if (event.target=== pointerDownElement) {
        console.log('triggering click');
    }
});
```

No need to assign a value to a variable if you're only going to use it once.  Also, event.preventDefault(); and return false; will guarantee the default behavior of the event doesn't take place (not that there typically is one for mousedown, but I'm assuming you have a reason for including this code).